# Yii2 activeform onchange label name for the same attribute value

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

In my dropdownlist, when I choose `Percentage`, the label of the `'vendorcommision'`(next field) should be `"Percentage"`. When I choose `Amount`, the label should be `"Amount"`

```
if($model->userType!="ADMIN" && $model->userType!="HOST"){
      echo $form->field($model, 'fixedOrPercentagevendor')
                    ->dropDownList(
                    [0=>'Amount',1=>'Percentage'],
                    [
                        'onchange'=>'if($(this).val() == 1){
                            $("#percentage").val("20");
                            }
                            else{
                            $("#percentage").val("1000");}'
                    ]);

    echo $form->field($model, 'vendorcommision')
                  ->label('Vendor Fee')
                  ->textInput(['type' => 'number','id' => 'percentage']);
    }
```

Comment: use javascript / jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

1. Turn label off for 'vendorcommision' [`->label(false)`]
2. Use a span for custom label, eg `<span class="custom-label"></span>`
3. Add event listener to the dropdown list to change labels. It will be on the lines of:

   ```
   var onChangeFunc = function(event) {
       if($(fixedOrPercentagevendorSelector).val() == 1) {
           $('.custom-label').html('Percentage');
       } else {
           $('.custom-label').html('Amount');
       }
   }
   ```

Note: If you include I18N support to your project, you will probably have to save the labels in some variable and use them.

Comment: Where to add label class?

Comment: If you are asking about Point 2, its just HTML. Use it where you want the label to appear, eg just before vendorcommision field. If its something else, I need some detail regarding your question to be able to answer that